# Django template language include variable

Tags: django, django-templates

In the [include documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include) they state that you can include a template contained in a variable.  However they do not explain how to write a template variable.

I am looking to do something like:

```
{% variable thing %}
  <div> Hello {{name}} </div>
{% endvariable thing %}

{# include the variables #}
{% include thing with name='Chris' %}
{% include thing with name='Julie' %}
```

Comment: So you have a key named 'thing' in your template context that has a template path like "foo/bar.html"? You have to add that in your view.

Comment: the variable keyword I made up because I'm not sure how to do it.  I want to include the template within the same file, not another file.  I realize I can just put my template in a separate html file and include it in another.  I was trying to avoid doing that since the variable thing will on be used in one file

Comment: You've misread the documentation. It says you can include a template file using a name taken from a variable, not that the template contents can be in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the template `thing.html`:

```
<div>Hello {{name}}</div>
```

And then in the main template include it:

```
{% include 'thing.html' with name='Chris' %}
{% include 'thing.html' with name='Julie' %}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to create the template thing in the same file?  That is what I am looking for

Comment: Maybe you are better off using a template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Comment: Do you want something like jinja macros? http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros No, Django's built-in template system doesn't support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

For your example you would need to add a key named 'thing' to your template context in your view. 'thing' would need a value like "foo/bar.html", a path to a template.

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {
    'thing': 'foo/bar.html'}, RequestContext(request))
```